# Livewire checkbox array only holding last-clicked value

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

So I have a list of checkboxes all wired to the same model. According to the docs, I should be able to get an array of these values within the model itself. However, when I click a series of these checkboxes, the model only holds the last-clicked value instead of an array of all clicked values. What could I be doing wrong?

Blade:

```
    <td>
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
            <input class="custom-control-input yesCV" id="9yesOD" wire:model.defer="colorvisionod" data-pair="9od" type="checkbox" value="9yesOD" />
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="9yes"></label>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
            <input class="custom-control-input yesCV" id="10yesOD" wire:model.defer="colorvisionod"  data-pair="10od" type="checkbox" value="10yesOD" />
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="10yesOD"></label>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
            <input class="custom-control-input yesCV" id="11yesOD" wire:model.defer="colorvisionod"  data-pair="11od" type="checkbox" value="11yesOD" />
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="11yesOD"></label>
        </div>
    </td>
<div class="w-100 pt-4 pb-2">                                
    <button type="button" wire:click="updateTechEncounter" class="rounded-0 py-2 btn btn-lg btn-common next-step next-button">Save All Information </button>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public $colorvisionod = [];
public function updateTechEncounter(){
    dd($this->colorvisionod);
}
```

This will dump the value of the last-clicked checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and it works fine *when you remove the `.defer`*. The `.defer` causes weird behaviour when saving to the array. It gives me the 3 values, but upon unchecking one it removed all values.

Other than that, when Livewire has a `wire:model` to an array, it will update the array. I've only had issues with fast clicks (if you click 2 checkboxes very quickly in sequence, it will uncheck the first). I solved this by adding `wire:loading.attr="disabled"` to each checkbox, which can help with weird checking/unchecking behaviour due to Livewire's magic check method.

I hope this helps. I was not able to exactly reproduce your problem.

Comment: thanks for the answer! this leads me to another question though. if i don't put "defer" AND don't save the array on update, the component re-renders with each checkbox click which starts them all over from an un-checked state. how do you handle that?

Comment: @maximus1127 How would you go and _not_ update the array? And why would you want that in the first place? Livewire sets the checked value on radio and checkbox inputs based on whether the `wire:model` on that element has that value. And so, on each re-render, it will check the variables attached to the `wire:model` and set the checkboxes as set or not. To adhere to Livewire's logic, it's simply the best to ensure the variables you want checked are in the array.

Comment: so, after many hours of playing around. i found my issue. I'm initiating the array to the value from the database on first page load. So in render() I'm setting ```$this->colorvisionod = $myModel->colorvisionod```. However, in my database, it was null and so it was overwriting the initiating property of the class and changing it from an empty array to a null value. Once I added ```$this->colorvisionod = $myModel->colorvisionod??[]``` everything worked fine.